# Change the value of the textbox when particular date is selected in php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the amount of the textbox when particular date is selected in the input type date.. When user clicks on date November 2nd The amount text box should be 100rs whereas when clicked on sundays amount is 500 and others amount will be 300.. How can i do it
Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#txtDate").change(function() {
    var selDate = new Date(this.value);
    if (selDate.getDay() == 0) { //If sunday, can change your logic here
      $(".form-control").val(500);
    } else {
      $(".form-control").val(300);
    }
  })
});
</script>



<input type="date" name="mass_date" id="txtDate" required="required" class="col-md-12"  min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days")); ?>" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2020-09-30"));?>"    value="<?php if(isset($_GET['mass_date'])) { echo $_GET['mass_date']; } ?>" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="slDay" name="amount"  />
```

Comment: `selDate.getDay()` on a sunday would be 6. Also does it have to be specific the 2'nd november or the day code aka 1?

Comment: Only on Specific 2nd November the amount has to be 100

Comment: No offense, but the documentation for `Date` would provide answers for all your questions and should be understandable for everyone - even a beginner: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#txtDate").change(function() {
    const selDate = new Date(this.value);
    const dayOfMonth = selDate.getDate();
    const month = selDate.getMonth() + 1;
    const dayOfWeek = selDate.getDay();

    if (month === 11 && dayOfMonth === 2) {
      $(".form-control").val(100);
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek === 0) {
      $(".form-control").val(500);
    }
    else {
      $(".form-control").val(300);
    }
  })
});
</script>



<input type="date" name="mass_date" id="txtDate" required="required" class="col-md-12"  min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days")); ?>" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2020-09-30"));?>"    value="<?php if(isset($_GET['mass_date'])) { echo $_GET['mass_date']; } ?>" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="slDay" name="amount"  />
```

Comment: He wants the value 500 on sundays, so it need to be dayOfWeek === 6

Comment: Quote from developer.mozilla.org: The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday. For the day of the month, see Date.prototype.getDate().

Comment: The op still wants it to be 500 at sundays and your code makes 500 on mondays

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen you have to select monday to get 500, if you run the snippet? What time zone do you live in?

Comment: OP says `clicked on sundays amount is 500` aka when you select a sunday he wants 500

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No, the value 0 as result of `Date::getDay` represents Sunday. If you observe another behavior, there's another reason.

Comment: When I click on a sunday in your code example it shows 300 in the textfield. and when I click on a monday it shows 500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223278/discussion-between-wuarmin-and-carsten-lovbo-andersen).